# Largest solution of $2\ln(e^x-1)=\ln2+\ln(e^x+3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been trying to solve this equation: $$2\ln(e^x-1)=\ln2+\ln(e^x+3).$$ I am asked for the equation's largest solution, and I come to a point where I get $\ln(e^x(e^x-4)) = \ln5$. I can't find my way forward. When I took a quick look at the answer, it's given to be $\ln5$, which quite disappoints me, because even though I keep solving, my workout doesn't seem to lead me to such an answer. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for any response! 
//Lloyd

Comment: How can we know what you are doing wrong, when you don't show us what you have done?

Comment: Anyway, from $\log(e^x(e^x-4))=\log5$, you should get $(e^x)^2-4e^x-5=0$, which is a quadratic equation for $e^x$, and you should be able to finish it off from there.

Comment: Answered analytically down below, I am sure it will help you understand the  method you follow when such a problem is called for solution !

Comment: Finally, generally for all your future posts or questions, make sure you approve the answer that fits you so they become answered as a thread

Comment: Thanks guy! Will try to be more precise next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is written as : $ \ln(e^x - 1)^2 = \ln(2e^x + 6)$

The logarithm function is $"1-1"$, so by definition, you get :

$(e^x - 1)^2 = 2e^x + 6 \Leftrightarrow e^{2x} - 2e^x + 1 = 2e^x + 6 \Leftrightarrow e^{2x} - 4e^x  - 5= 0. $

Set $y = e^x$ and then $y^2 = e^{2x} $ and solve the : $ y^2 - 4y - 5 = 0$, find the solutions for y and then just substitute for $y=e^x$ and you have your solutions.

Comment: That was so helpful man!

Comment: Thanks mate ! Make sure you approve the answer if it's the one that fits you the most !

Answer (score 0):

To find the largest solution of $2\ln(e^x-1)=\ln2+\ln(e^x+3)$, use the logarithmic identities $a \cdot \ln(b)=\ln(b^a)$ and $\ln(a) + \ln(b) = \ln(a \cdot b)$ to obtain
$$
\ln\left( (e^x-1)^2 \right) = \ln\left( 2 \cdot (e^x+3) \right).
$$
If you exponentiate both sides, you get
$$
(e^x-1)^2 = 2 \cdot (e^x+3).
$$
Now we can use a trick: We substitute $y = e^x-1$ to get
$$
y^2 = 2 \cdot (y + 4),
$$
which is simply a quadratic equation. Its two solutions are $y_1 = 4$ and $y_2 = -2$. If you substitute back, you obtain
$$
x_1 = \ln(y_1 + 1) = \ln(5) \qquad\text{and}\qquad x_2 = \ln(y_2 + 1) = \ln(-1).
$$
However, only $x_1$ makes sense in the realm of real numbers; so, the only (and therefore largest) solution is $x = \ln(5)$.

Comment: Super duktig Björn! Det där stämde jättebra!!